# HP envy x360 15.6 touchscreen will not work

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

just got HP envy x360, seems to be a hybrid of the envy and spectre. Black case, 1080 display, spectre wifi card, and many other things I didnt order but they upgraded to and sent from China. Kinda cool, but, I cannot get the touchscreen to work. Works fine in Windows, but not on Ubuntu 16.04. Running a dual boot.Any work arounds, suggestions?,

Comment: also wont go to tablet mode

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, this model M6-AR004DX has an ELAN0732 I2C touchscreen controller.  The module `hid_multitouch` (when manually loaded with `modprobe`) doesn't do anything, nor does `elants_i2c`.  I found some other kernel bug reports from late last year pertaining to the gpio interrupts on the AMD processor, which this thing apparently relies on, not working correctly, but that was supposedly fixed.  Now it just silently fails to be detected.

You can see if this is the device by examining the directory `/sys/bus/i2c/devices`

Also, if you are trying to use `NetworkManager` to setup your WiFi on this particular laptop, and are having problems where the adapter seemingly doesn't want to stay enabled, you should check for the existence of and remove the module `acer_hid`.  `lsmod | grep -i acer`, if there's anything in the list `lsmod -r` that sucker and see if `NetworkManager` works normally.  If it does, blacklist that module and it will stay fixed upon reboot.

FWIW, I had both of these problems using the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS live media, as well as a recent Arch Linux install.

Comment: Hi & welcome :) Are you saying the touchscreen just will not work no matter what? Is there a bug report (on Launchpad, ideally)?

Comment: No bug report re: the touchscreen, at least not from me.  I submitted one about acer_wmi, however.

Comment: I'm working with the vendor and driver maintainer to get this device added and working.  So far they think it will work with the generic HID-multitouch and i2c-hid modules with some minor tweaks.  I'll post back if we come up with a working patch.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715 for the upcoming kernel patches